# NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am extracting data from an API and convert that into a Pandas data frame. The pandas data frame contains the data as below

```
               **session_id            visitor_id                 server_time                  updated_at       referrer_type      device_type**
0      316046440780942428  14256666432883430808  2023-03-01T22:18:13.515749  2023-03-01T22:18:16.000000   [1, Direct entry]  [1, Smartphone]
1     1559381029125193934   6223493451404765687  2023-03-01T22:18:12.466276  2023-03-01T22:18:16.000000  [2, Search engine]  [1, Smartphone]
2     1634055602528061570   3488177825412806861  2023-03-01T22:18:12.609022  2023-03-01T22:18:16.000000   [1, Direct entry]  [1, Smartphone]
3     2336103663959038531   8418933936834842610  2023-03-01T22:18:12.559650  2023-03-01T22:18:16.000000        [3, Website]     [0, Desktop]
4     3848276761860900650   8640986235790038067  2023-03-01T22:16:30.337437  2023-03-01T22:18:16.000000  [2, Search engine]  [1, Smartphone]
```

I would like replace all NULL values for **referrer_type** & **device_type** with a list/array of [-1, 'Unknown'] and written a code as below

```
df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), ['referrer_type']] = df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), 'referrer_type'].apply(lambda x: [-1, 'Unknown'])

df.loc[df['device_type'].isnull(), ['device_type']] = df.loc[df['device_type'].isnull(), 'device_type'].apply(lambda x: [-1, 'Unknown'])
```

But I am getting an error
*NumPy boolean array indexing assignment requires a 0 or 1-dimensional input, input has 2 dimensions*

Any help is most appreciated

The same code works in google colab, but when I tried it in Pycharm it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could just assign like this:

```
df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), 'referrer_type'] = df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), 'referrer_type'].apply(lambda x: [-1, 'Unknown'])

df.loc[df['device_type'].isnull(), 'device_type'] = df.loc[df['device_type'].isnull(), 'device_type'].apply(lambda x: [-1, 'Unknown'])
```

This `df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), ['referrer_type']]` is a `pd.DataFrame`, this `df.loc[df['referrer_type'].isnull(), 'referrer_type']` is a `pd.Series`